# Check values in array without using a loop

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

i'm trying to check two values and if they are met do something if not obviously throw an error. Now the problem im having is that the array needs to be completely checked before the error has to be thrown.
EX:

- in my sheet i have a letter d
- in my array CODELIJST i have the following values - [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]
- when we loop the first time the else statement is active because d != a
  -> how can i loop trough whole array and if the value is not there throw an error?

```
    (let u=1; u < CODELIJST.length; ++u){
     if (CODELIJST[u][0]==shift) {
      var testvar2 = CODELIJST[u][1];
     }else{
     // throw error if value is not found
     }
    }
```

The Array is two dimensional thats why im only looping through with var u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`else if`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) and [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break):

```
if (CODELIJST[u][0] === shift) {
  var testvar2 = CODELIJST[u][1];
  break;
} else if (u === CODELIJST.length) {
```

Comment: Thanks for the o so simple solution, didn't think so far as when counter is at max you can throw error. Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED:** As recommended by TheMaster, using `array.forEach` instead of `array.map` since this doesn't have a return value. This checks each array element if it's a string or not without using a loop.

**Try this:**

```
function checkArrayValType() {

  var d, f = 2; 
  var array = ['a','b','c',d,'e',f];

  array.forEach(val = index => (typeof index === "string") ? console.log("String") : console.log("not string"))

}
```

This is a sample implementation to check if the values within an array is a string or not using `array.map` function.

**References:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

[image]

Comment: If you're not going to use the return array,  it's better to use `array.forEach()` instead. See Anti pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I'll edit my answer as recommended